# How do I remove the dots in LineChartView iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, linechart, ios-charts

I'm learning [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I was using the tutorial found [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/). The first picture shows the result I am getting. How do you remove the blue circle dots so that it only shows a smooth line like what is shown in the second picture? 
[image: This is the result I am getting]

[image: This is what I am trying to get]

Here is snippet of the code

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ChartsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    lineChartView.data = lineChartData

}

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `.setDrawCircles = NO;` of your `LineDataSet` set to disable the drawing of circle.

It was on the wiki...
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/DataSet-classes-in-detail

Comment: the question was for ios-chart. This mpandroidchart is for android and some of the functions in there are not available in ios-chart

Comment: That's what I was searching for for android is the same but instead of no use `setDrawCircleHole(false)` and `setDrawCircles(false)`

Answer (score 10):

to remove circle in a line

```
lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
```

to remove value alone in a circle

```
lineChartData.drawValuesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers, you can use these properties to make your line more smooth

```
lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
lineChartDataSet.drawCubicEnabled = true
```

or you can use mode property as drawCubicEnabled property is deprecated

```
lineChartDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
lineChartDataSet.cubicIntensity = 0.2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 0
```